# How to pass a list of objects using intent?

Tags: android

How can I pass a list of objects to another activity ?

Im trying this and its not working...

**Activity A**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("list",listCsv);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,i);
finish();
```

**Activity B**

```
ArrayList<Contato> lAgenda = 
(ArrayList<Contato>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("lista");
```

And in my `Activity` B my list `lAgenda` doesnt get the list of the `Activity` A,
I got a `NULL` value.

My ContatoVO class

```
public class ContatoVO implements Serializable,Parcelable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private long id;
    private String nome;
    private String endereco;
    private String telefone;
    private String estado;
    private int idEstado;


        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getIdEstado()
        {
            return idEstado;
        }

        public void setIdEstado(int id)
        {
            this.idEstado = id;
        }

        public String getEstado() {
            return estado;
        }

        public void setEstado(String estado) {
            this.estado = estado;
        }

        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }

        public void setNome(String value) {
            this.nome = value;
        }

        public String getEndereco() {
            return endereco;
        }

        public void setEndereco(String value) {
            this.endereco = value;
        }

        public String getTelefone() {
            return telefone;
        }

        public void setTelefone(String value) {
            this.telefone = value;
        }
        // Will be used by the ArrayAdapter in the ListView
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return nome;
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

            dest.writeString(nome);
            dest.writeString(endereco);
            dest.writeString(telefone);
        }

}
```

Function that sends data intent to Activity

```
public final void lerCsv(Context context)
    {

        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
        ArrayList<ContatoVO> listaCsv = new ArrayList<ContatoVO>();

        try
        {
            InputStream iStream = assetManager.open("teste.csv");
            InputStreamReader iStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(iStream);
            CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(iStreamReader,';');

            String[] registro = null;

            //pula cabeçalho
            csvReader.readNext();

            while((registro = csvReader.readNext()) != null)
            {

                ContatoVO contato = new ContatoVO();
                contato.setNome(registro[0]);
                contato.setEndereco(registro[1]);
                contato.setTelefone(registro[2]);

                listaCsv.add(contato);

            }

            csvReader.close();

            Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);

            i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("lista",listaCsv);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,i);
            finish();
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Where i Try to get this data(list)

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        ArrayList<ContatoVO> lAgendaVO = null;
        try {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                lAgendaVO = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra("lista");

                lContatoDAO.open();     
                lContatoDAO.InserirListaCsv(lAgendaVO);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            trace("Erro : " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key you are using to retrieve the ArrayList doesn't match the one you are using to write it onto the bundle. You have to be consistent. Use either `list` or `lista`. I strongly suggest you to use constants. E.g

ActivityA

```
public static final String LIST_KEY = "LIST_KEY";
Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
i.putParcelableArrayListExtra(LIST_KEY,listCsv);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,i);
finish();
```

ActivityB

```
ArrayList<Contato> lAgenda = 
         (ArrayList<Contato>) getIntent(). getParcelableArrayList(ActivityA.LIST_KEY);
```

if the snippet to retrieve the `List` is part of `onActivityResult`, you have to use the former parameter `Intent data` instead of  `getIntent()`

As Pointed out by @Sergey, you have to be consistent also on the put*/get* you use. If `Contato` is `Parcelable` (highly recommended), use `getParcelableArrayList`  instead of `getSerializableExtra` .

**Edit**:

you need the constructor that takes a `Parcel`

```
protected ContatoVO(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readLong();
    nome = in.readString();
    endereco = in.readString();
    telefone = in.readString();
    estado = in.readString();
    idEstado = in.readInt();
}
```

you writeToParcel is not writing all the field. Change it to:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeLong(id);
    dest.writeString(nome);
    dest.writeString(endereco);
    dest.writeString(telefone);
    dest.writeString(estado);
    dest.writeInt(idEstado);
}
```

And you missed `Parcelable.Creator`

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static final Parcelable.Creator<ContatoVO> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ContatoVO>() {
    @Override
    public ContatoVO createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ContatoVO(in);
    }

    @Override
    public ContatoVO[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ContatoVO[size];
    }
};
```

}

Comment: Also, in ActivityA used `putParcelableArrayListExtra()` and in ActivityB used `getSerializableExtra()`.

Comment: I am using lista and the both cases...i just edited lista to list because lista is in portuguese

Comment: are you using onActivityResult ?

Comment: yes im am protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  ArrayList<ContatoVO> lAgendaVO = null;
  
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   
    
    lAgendaVO = data.getParcelableArrayExtra("lista");

Comment: is `ContatoVO` parcelable ?

Comment: yes , public class ContatoVO implements Serializable,Parcelable

Comment: can you post it ? Edit your question

Comment: and what parameter i have to pass now where I am instancing an object of ContatoVO ?

Comment: create an empty one. `public ContatoVO() {}` . This is called overloading in java

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return result of `startActivityForResult`
and you are using `putParcelableArrayListExtra` which uses `ArrayList` containing **parcelable** objects you shoud be consistent and when receiving data use

```
@Override

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      .... = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra("list")
}
```

Comment: I cant do this because my lAgenda is a list not a Parcelable[] I have fucntion that is expecting a list